# TCPServer with simultaneous full duplex communication

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I am trying to write a c# server/client that will simultaneously send byte arrays over TCP across each other.  I'm trying to wrap my head around how to accomplish this.  All of the example I have seen wait for a message, then send a response.  I need communication to happen simultaneously.

Would I need to create 2 separate TCP socket connections for ingoing & outgoing on both the server & client?  Can I pass data simultaneously with 1 connection in a "full duplex" fashion?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise you to look at the asynchronous sockets. The reason is, that they don't block threads while receiving or sending data.

```
Socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, size, endReceiveMethod);
```

The endreceive method will be called when there are bytes received. (on a other thread)
This is the same for sending.

```
Socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, size, endSendMethod);
```

*I remember in the early days I was worried about reading and writing on the same thread, creating difficult constructions with read-timeouts etc and each client it's own thread.*

This isn't needed with Asynchronous sockets. It doesn't use a single thread per client. It uses I/O Completion Ports *http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx* instead of blocking threads.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using select() method to listen on server and client file descriptor (or fd). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx

Basically, if you have a TCP server, let us say, fd0 and if the client sends a connect, then the server fd would create a new fd for the new connection, let us call it fd1. Now, you would want to do three things with these: (a) listen for newer incoming connections on fd0, (b) wait for reciving data on fd1, and (c) send data on fd1. Sending data is usually non-blocking, so you dont have to worry about that. But, for (a) and (b), you can use a select.. If there is data to be read on fd1, then you would get a read event. Likewise, if there is a new connection on fd0, then also you would get a read event and you can call accept.